# tidyverse and native pipe

Tags: r, pipe

Can someone explain why in the following code (taken from Hadley, R for Data Science, Chapter 13, print, First Edition)

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) # Works
mtcars |>  split(.$cyl) # Does not work
```

the third line throws an error saying

```
#Error in split.data.frame(mtcars, .$cyl) : object '.' not found
```

I thought that the pipe `%>%` and the native pipe `|>` could be used interchangeably.
Using R.4.2. Is it generally a bad idea to use the native pipe implemented in RStudio?

Comment: You can use underscore as a placeholder in the latest version of R

Comment: 2nd/work-in-progress edition of Hardley's R4DS includes section *"5.3 |> vs %>%"* - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-pipes.html#vs .  It's up to date, describes `_` placeholder and it's current limitations (i.e not supporting operators like `$`, `[[`, `[` with `_`)

Comment: Thanks for all your your answers. The third comment by "marusl" was very helpful. Thanks again to the community!